Suspension (and even sometimes powering off) fails
I use Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (dual boot with Windows 11) and a dekstop PC (Asus PRIME H-410M-K rev 1.0 + i7-10700 with built-in graphics).
When I try to suspend, the screen is off and the power led blinks at it should, but fans are still spinning and can't wake up again (I have to press for four seconds the power button and lose the session).
Also, after long sessions, sometimes the PC doesn't power off completely after telling Ubuntu to power off. Fans keep spinning.
None of this happens on Windows. The only weird thing that could happen with this OS is that it sometimes wakes up alone if I keep some windows non-minimized here, or it randomly is able to wake up with keyboard or mouse (this is not consistent). But it is always able to suspend and power off completely.
Is there any way to fix this on Ubuntu, or may be a motherboard problem?
